# how can I fix the .ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

when I put a gap between quotation marks " " I have ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and when I close quotation marks "" inside the split it shows on my board the first letter of firstname and the first letter of lastname.More spesific the console shows problem in (UserServiceImpl.java:68),(UserServiceImpl.java:60),(UserServiceImpl.java:61),(AuthController.java:60)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDto {
    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email should not be empty")
    @Email
    private String email;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password should not be empty")
    private String password;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository,
                           RoleRepository roleRepository,
                           PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(UserDto userDto) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(userDto.getFirstName() + " " + userDto.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());

        //encrypt the password once we integrate spring security
        //user.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        if(role == null){
            role = checkRoleExist();
        }
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(role));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserDto> findAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        return users.stream().map((user) -> convertEntityToDto(user))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private UserDto convertEntityToDto(User user) {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        String[] name = user.getName().split(" ");
        userDto.setFirstName(name[0]);
        userDto.setLastName(name[1]);
        userDto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        return userDto;
    }

    private Role checkRoleExist() {
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        return roleRepository.save(role);
    }
}


@Controller
public class AuthController {

    private UserService userService;

    public AuthController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }


  
    @PostMapping("/register/save")
    public String registration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") UserDto user,
                               BindingResult result,
                               Model model) {
        User existing = userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (existing != null) {
            result.rejectValue("email", null, "There is already an account registered with that email");
        }
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            return "register";
        }
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/register?success";

    }

        @GetMapping("/users")
    public String listRegisteredUsers(Model model){
        List<UserDto> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "users";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user `name` field may not have a space in it, i.e. has just one component, in which case referencing the second element of the array after splitting would result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Try catering to this possibility to avoid the error.

```java
private UserDto convertEntityToDto(User user) {
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
    String[] names = user.getName().split(" ");
    userDto.setFirstName(names[0]);
    userDto.setLastName(names.length > 1 ? names[1] : "");
    userDto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    return userDto;
}
```